# How to check owner of delta table in Databricks

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

What query should i run to get details of owner of delta table in Databricks

I have tried describe table extended command it's showing owner as root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
SHOW GRANTS ON <schema>.<tablename>;
```

The entry with be `actionType = 'OWN'` determines ownership.

Databricks documentation: [object privileges](https://docs.databricks.com/security/access-control/table-acls/object-privileges.html#object-ownership).

Comment: While running that comment i am getting an error like unity catalog is not enabled on this cluster

Comment: This usually happens if you reference a table using full catalog path (like <catalog>.<schema>.<tablename>).

Comment: Thank you it's working,but I am able to view details of table where I am also having owner permission. On other cases it's not working